# center of a group 4

Tags: group-theory

Sorry for the simplicity of the question, but about which conditions we will
have

$Z(G)K/K=Z(G/K)$ where $1\not=K\trianglelefteq G$ and $G$ is not abelian? I
know that is always worth $Z(G)K/K\leq Z(G/K)$

$K\leq Z(G)\,\ $is enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
H / K = Z(G / K),
$$
then $H = \{ a \in G : [a, G] \subseteq K \}$.

Here $[a, G] = \{ [a, g] : g \in g \}$, and $[a, g] = a^{-1} g^{-1} a g$.

So to guarantee that $H = Z(G) K$ you have to assume the condition that there is no element $a \in G \setminus Z(G) K$ such that $[a, G] \subseteq K$.

At the moment I do not see anything better than this, which is admittedly a *very slight reformulation*.

Note also that in a nilpotent group the upper central series ends in $G$ (by definition, you may say), that is, if you start with $Z_{1}(G) = Z(G)$, and then define $Z_{i+1}(G)/Z_{i}(G) = Z(G/Z_{i}(G))$, you will eventually get $Z_{n}(G) = G$, so the property seriously fails in this class of groups, and this shows that $K \le Z(G)$ is definitely not enough.

The dihedral group of order $8$ provides an example, for instance.

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G=S_3$, $K=Z_3 <G$. Then $Z(G)K/K=1\ne Z(G/K)=G/K$.

"$K≤Z(G)$ is enough?" - No.

Comment: I agree that $K\leq Z(G)$ is not enough, but it does not hold in this example.

Comment: You may take a nonabelian nilpotent group for an example where $K \le Z(G)$ is not enough.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: I did ;-)

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen me too ;-)

Comment: User2040: Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

In any non-abelian $p$-group, taking the quotient by the (non-trivial) center again gives a group with non-trivial center. This shows that even $K=Z(G)$ is not enough to get $Z(G)K/K=Z(G/K)$.

Comment: User2040: Thank you for the explanation